# variable "Not defined" when I call the function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the code a bit more compact by defining initialisation functions for a game (NOT `__init__` ), but after calling the function I can't get some objects that where defined inside the function.

To be more specific, if my function is:

```
def beginning():
    d = Deck()
    game_deck = d.thedeck(suit,values)
```

but when I run `beginning()` and want to print `d` or `game_deck` I get "not defined"

Comment: Is `beginning()` part of a class?

Comment: `d` and `game_deck` are local variables in `beginning`. Are you expecting those names to exist outside the function? That's not how locals work.

Comment: whenever you get an error, you must not "reinvent" the error message but copy the original error message along the full traceback into the question itself.

Comment: @Carl: That won't make any difference here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well he would need to pass `self` to beginning, and then he could possibly make `d` into `self.d` and get access to it, since it appears as if that is what he is trying to do. Just asking since he specifically mentioned `__init__`

Comment: thank you all, I didn't have it clear how local and global where working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `d` and `game_deck` are local variables in `beginning` then you won't be able to access them game the function executes. Instead, try declaring them in the global scope.

```
d = None
game_deck = None


def beginning():
    global d
    global game_deck

    d = Deck()
    game_deck = d.thedeck(suit,values)
```